# node wrangler while editing a group

Tags: materials, node-editor, add-on

The awesome addon node wrangler works perfectly when I am trying to use a node viewer in material edition.
Except when I am editing a group:

I create a node group (CTRL G)
in my group on an image node for example: SHIFT CTRL CLICK... I can see the operation is called in console output (bpy.ops.node.nw_emission_viewer()), but nothing happen on my node.

Am I missing something or is a case for which the viewer cannot be created?

Maybe one specificity in my case, I am factorizing my materials: The group contains the output node

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the node wrangler addon <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> connects the node to the material output node and adds an emission shader if the node output is not a shader. The material output node shouldn't be used inside a node group so node wrangler does not make that shortcut active when editing a node group.

You should have the material output node in the material node tree and connect the group output to the material output node, not have the material output node inside a node group.

It is not possible to make a connection from a node inside a group to the active material output node that is outside the group. As connecting the node to the group output does not guarantee that the output will then be connected to the material output and the group could be in use by several materials, it makes little sense to use it inside a node group.

Comment: While I agree, I still think that there's a reason to preview the result of the material at the point when inside of the node group (especially when seeking errors in material setup / unknown effects etc.). It's possible to exclude group from the node chain altogether, of course, although it's may be too drastic changing. Overall it's possible to preview result of the group inside group with one more Material Output node inside of that group (and delete it once preview is done); it's more a hack though.

Comment: thanks sambler. Actually I have my reasons (good reasons I think) to keep my output node inside the group. So as far as I understand, the answer to my answer is basically "no it's not possible" :-). Thanks a lot for your time!